# How to solve a Cauchy problem of a semilinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, cauchy-problem

I am trying to solve the following:

$ u(x,y) u_x (x,y) + u_y(x,y)=0 \\ 
 x\in\mathbb{R},  y>0\\
$

with the condition $u(0,y)=y, y>0$

Starting with the characteristics I find that for $u=z$ (that is the way I have been taught to solve such problems)

$ \frac{dx}{ds}=z $

$ \frac{dy}{ds}=1 $

$ \frac{dz}{ds}=0 $

In other cases where for example $\frac{dz}{ds}=1$, I would go on like this $\frac{dx}{z}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{1}$ and manipulate this system in order to get an expression for $x,y,z$ and extract two new equations $\phi$ and $\psi$.

Any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated

Comment: You are on a good track. Setting $y(0) = y_0$, we find $y = s + y_0$. Since $z = y_0$ is constant along characteristics, we deduce $x = y_0 s$ from $x(0) = 0$. Now, you may finish

Comment: @Korina Moss. You made a mistake in writing $\frac{dx}{z}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{1}$.The correct Charpit-Lagrange system of characteristic ODEs is : $$ds=\frac{dx}{z}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{0}$$ .

Comment: @JJacquelin I was just pointing out the normal cases I've worked on so far as an example, not the case. If you read the three previous lines you will see that I have already written the correct characteristics.

Comment: I don't understand what you call "the normal case". Doesn't matter. OK. I was aware that your three ODEs separately written are correct. They are equivalent to the Charpit-Lagrange system if the denominator of the third fraction is $0$ but not $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$u\:u_x+u_y=0$$
System of characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{0}$$
This implies $du=0$ and so a first characteristic equation :
$$u=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from  $\frac{dx}{c_1}=\frac{dy}{1}\quad\implies\quad c_1y-x=c_2$
$$u\:y-x=c_2$$
The general solution expressed on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$y\:u-x=F(u)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function to be determined according to the boundary condition.

CONDITION : $u(0,y)=y\quad\implies\quad y\:y-0=F(y)$
$$F(y)=y^2$$
Now the function $F$ is known. We put it into the above general solution where the argument is $(u)$ thus $F(u)=u^2$ :
$$y\:u-x=u^2$$
Solving for $u$ leads to :
$$u=\frac12\left(y\pm\sqrt{y^2-4x} \right)$$
The condition $u(0,y)=y$ and $y>0$ determines the sign. The solution is :
$$u(x,y)=\frac12\left(y+\sqrt{y^2-4x} \right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much @JJacquelin!